# How Prevent Multiple Copies Of React from Loading?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, webpack

In my previous Meteor app, using browserify, and React, all was working until I switched to [meteor webpack](https://github.com/jedwards1211/meteor-webpack-react).

I use [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/) in my Meteor apps and it worked great but with browserify I could prevent multiple copies of react from loading which prevents this error I'm now having:

```
Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://fb.me/react-refs-must-have-owner).
```

My package.json look this:

```
...

"dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.1.3",
    "lodash": "^3.10.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-beta8"
  },

...
```

Is there a configuration in webpack I could use something call externals? Not fully sure what that means but a comment said to use:

```
externals: {
  'react': 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
}
```

Comment: Looks like multiple versions of react used.  stackoverflow.com/questions/34236426/how-to-fix-react-error-uncaught-error-invariant-violation-addcomponentasrefto/34358537#34358537

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you use webpack, you can add an alias for loading react, like this:

```
// In webpack.config.js

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('node_modules/react'),
    },
  },
```

This prevented the `addComponentAsRefTo(...)` error and made our build succeed again. However, for some reason, the testing build failed only on our CI environment as it could not resolve the `node_modules/react` path. I think it's unlikely that you will encounter this particular problem, though.

Comment: This solution saved me! Thank you.

Comment: `react: require.resolve('react')` also seems to work, and should continue to work wherever the `react` module is located.

Comment: It could be a mismatch in your deps. Uninstall your dependency, `react-select` in this case, check the `react` version of your dependency and install it. Install again your dependency and `npm` should dedupe it from your peer dependencies instead of creating a new copy. The doc also explains the three cases that can produce this error https://reactjs.org/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html

Answer (score 2):

Something that worked for me was:

Uninstall all globally installed packages related to react (create-react-app, react-native, react and so on)

then: `rm -rf node_modules`

then: use `npm install` instead of yarn install

considering an App created with crate-react-app and ejected

Comment: Typo in crate-react-app; I think you might mean `create-react-app`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was building a separate npm module, then including that as a library in another project locally using `npm link ../some-library`. One of the modules within that library caused this error when I ran the parent project.

When I ran into this error, the solution for me was to prevent react and react-dom from being including in the some-library bundle output, by adding the following to the module.exports of its webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom'
}
```

Comment: I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined" when adding this to my config.

Answer (score 1):

If You use web pack then you can fix it by adding the following to Webpack config
for Don't bundle react or react-dom

`externals: {
  'react': 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
}`