# Why does VS Code consider an import valid but WebPack does not?

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, webpack-3

I am pretty sure it is all about the version of WebPack I use (`"webpack-cli": "3.3.11"`) but I want to be sure I am right before going on another journey of debugging for upgrading WebPack (I tried to upgrade it to 5 but it does not work without a config file, I am just stretching the limit against the read-the-manual instruction).

In the `tsconfig.base.js` I have this:

```json
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["src/*"]
}
```

(The reason for using a separate `tsconfig.base.json` is in the question I linked to below.)

Then there is this:

```
import { RegistrationStepManager } from "@/helpers";
```

in file `./src/some/path/RegistrationStepper.tsx`.

Running `npm start` with CRA and `react-scripts v4.0.3` shows an error without crashing:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/some/path/RegistrationStepper.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/helpers' in '/my-path/my-project/src/some/other/path'.
```

VS Code tooltips and autocompletion show everything is imported well, no red squiggles, just some ignoreable warnings.

I think that the alias for `"@/*"` is not working well but, because VS Code works well with it, I think it might be a bug.

How does TS work with WebPack when it comes to this failure? Do I have to upgrade to WebPack 5?

Another question from the same day, from me, on the same code, maybe it is relevant here too: [How can I import an enum through an intermediate TS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67949040/258462).

Thanks.

## Update 1

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179673/258462) and I am going to migrate from CRA to WebPack without CRA since the project I am working on is not just for playing. Please, if you can, suggest me a guide to migrate from CRA to WebPack. I think the issue at the start of this question is about some missing WebPack configuration. I already have an old WebPack config file that might be causing a part of the issue.

Comment: You are on the right track. Currently CRA does not support typescript aliases, so you either have to augment it with something like react-app-rewired or craco. I would recommend migrating away from CRA if you can. There are tons of tutorials out there on how to build a react project with typescript and webpack without CRA

Comment: @SethLutske Thank you for the confirmation and for reassuring me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a WebPack config file that was not actually used. I was actually using CRA. So I started using [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and WebPack v4 as an intermediate solution till I start using "pure" WebPack. In `config-overrides.js` I put:

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  webpack: function(config, env) {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        plugins: [
          ...config.resolve.plugins,
          new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
          }),
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
```

After migrating to [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and making this change, the `Failed to compile.` error is gone. This also solves the issue in [How can I import an enum through an intermediate TS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67949040/258462).