# Failed to compile: npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After Installing Webpack the following command does not allow me to progress further in my project.

```
npm run build
```

**Error on Console**

```
> react-complete-guide@0.1.0 build C:\Users\pythonbuddha\Desktop\to_experiment\to-do-list
> node scripts/build.js

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

        ./node_modules/nanoid/index.browser.js:35

Read more here: bit.ly/2tRViJ9

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-complete-guide@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pythonbuddha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-08T10_56_07_043Z-debug.log
```

The link **Read more here: bit.ly/2tRViJ9** has no explanation for such issues.

Comment: are you building a react app ?

Comment: @PawanBishnoi, yes. I am building a react app.

Comment: then create using react-create-app and if you want to modify config then run eject command.

Comment: @PawanBishnoi, the project is already created with create-react-app command. Now I am solving problem to use WebPack.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627536/the-token-is-not-a-valid-statement-separator-in-this-version/65627596?noredirect=1#comment116032615_65627596

Comment: see this url :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129451/configuration-for-create-react-app-after-ejecting-to-build-a-component-library

Comment: you should also visit:- https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741

Comment: https://medium.com/breathelife/keeping-up-with-create-react-app-after-ejecting-8d5a26664d27

Comment: thanks, very funny article: https://medium.com/breathelife/keeping-up-with-create-react-app-after-ejecting-8d5a26664d27

I am on step 5. And now trying to solve the problem.